# Unity 2022.2.0 'Removing null node error' in animator

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2022.2.0b3 for my project and when I use the animator tab 3 errors appear.

> Removing null node
> UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph:OnEnable ()
> Edge.toNode is null
> UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph:OnEnable ()
> Edge.fromNode is null
> UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph:OnEnable ()

The error only appears if the animator tab is open when I run the scene. But it doesn't show up in different versions(like 2021).

So is this a error specific to the beta version(2022) or am I just doing something wrong?

Please ask for more information if needed. Really frustrated right now.

Answer (score 0):

... Report this to Unity? It's a beta, you shouldn't be using it for your main project.

[image]